# Jenkins & Android emulator: Emulator did not appear to start; giving up

Tags: android, android-emulator, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I would like test our android applications via Jenkins. I configured everything, but i got this error message:

> [android] Emulator did not appear to start; giving up

I found a solution for this problem from [here](http://hanscappelle.blogspot.hu/2013/01/jenkins-android-emulator-plugin-problems.html)

> This one can have several reasons. One of them is listed in the error below. I didn't encounter this myself but I've read on stackoverflow while looking for a solution to my specific issue. It seems to be related to the revision of the android sdk tools. On windows there was a fix like stated in this ticket: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-10815
>   However there seems to be a similar issue on linux that isn't fixed yet (at least the ticket is still open): https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-14901

**Solution**: The proposed solution in that ticket is to create a link with the name emulator (back original) towards the appropriate emulator-X bin.

I tried it and solved our problem, but only some builds, after that I got again this message. That's why i removed the android plugin and deleted the sdk folder, so i reinstall everything. After that there were 4 success builds. (Interesting, that i didn't create emulator link like than before) But it was all, the problem backed. I played with configuration and set 30 second delay for emulator start and checked the "delete emulator after build" option. I thought that the problem solved because I had 14!!! success build but the problem backed again :(
And now there is a new error message too:

> NAND: could not write file /tmp/android-jenkins/emulator-CaWkYU, File exists
>   [android] Emulator did not appear to start; giving up

What are you thinking, what is the problem? With same setting sometimes success, sometimes not. Why?

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19955837/android-emulator-did-not-appear-to-start-giving-up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i found the problem in the source code:
[AndroidEmulator.java](https://github.com/jenkinsci/android-emulator-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/android_emulator/AndroidEmulator.java)

The adb connection timeout is 1min and it's fix:

```
 private static final int ADB_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MS = 60 * 1000;
```

So i increment it to 5 mins, build a new plugin and installed and it solved my problem (~100 build without this problem)

Comment: How did you increase this? I found AndroidEmulator.class in a jar file - I'm not sure how to increase the tmeout from within there.

Comment: @UtkarshSinha “build a new plugin” is a dead give away on how he increased it: Download the source, change it and recompile.

Answer (score 2):

How many build executors do you have (default is 2)? I bet you can only have one emulator running on your Jenkins server at a time, when two jobs are trying to execute, one job is getting clobbered. If this is the case, you may want to consider the [Heavy Build plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Heavy+Job+Plugin) to lock up all executors when an Android job goes by. Or use slaves.

Comment: I always start builds manually when there is no build in progress. Now i added shell scripts into build steps, because the new idea is that the emulator process doesen't stop after build.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [pull request](https://github.com/jenkinsci/android-emulator-plugin/pull/63) which has fixes for this issue. Before merging PR to the main repo and get new plugin version, just download project from the author's forked repo and run command:

```
mvn install
```

from the project root directory. After that take "android-emulator.hpi" file located in

```
"<project root>/target"
```

directory and update/install plugin from the Jenkins Web UI

```
Manage Jenkins -> Manage Plugins -> Advanced
```

then reboot Jenkins CI. In project configuration use option

```
"Build Environment" -> "Common Emulator Options" -> "Advanced" -> "Adb timeout"
```

set it to 300 sec, for instance.